# Is it possible to duplicate the visual code side bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know a way to duplicate the visual code side bar. I would find it useful to be able to open different views at the same time as it happens in eclipse Theila (both share same source code)
[Eclipse Theila](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMRSF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

See my newer answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69329503/836330

[image: Side Panel demo]

You can put another panel on the right, in addition to the Side Bar and Panel.  And then drag various views into it.

---

1. Put the Panel on the right.  Right-click on one of the headers, like "Terminal" and select `Move Panel Right".
2. Drag your "Outline" header into that right Panel.

[image: move outline to the right]