# In Visual Studio Code, is there a way to see the explorer on the left and the outline on the right?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, outline-view

I am used to program having the file browser on the left of the code and the outline on the right. However, in Visual Studio Code it seems that I can only have both things on the same side. Is there any way to have them in different sides (like in the image, that comes from eclipse)?

Thanks,

DMR

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Coming to Stable v1.64, see [Release Notes: Side Panel](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_64.md#new-side-panel) so no need for the `experimental` settings.

Note that this second Side Bar is currently known as the ***Side Panel***.

You can drag various views into the Side Panel like the Outline or SCM views.  I would expect that more will be added later.

Demos:

[image: opening a Side Panel on the right demo]

[image: side panel demo]

---

This icon on the upper right was recently: it is a `Layout Control` icon.

[image: show panel icon]

> Customize Layout Control
>
> With all these new layout options, we have been exploring ways to
> better expose layout configuration for discoverability and ease of
> use. That's why you might notice a new experimental layout control in
> your title bar. Note this only appears if your `window.titleBarStyle`
> setting is custom and `workbench.experimental.layoutControl.enabled`
> is set to true. The enablement is controlled by an experiment, but if
> you want to enable it manually, you can do so in the Settings editor.
>
> The contents of the menu are still being worked on, but currently you
> should see the ability to toggle the Side Bar, Panel, and Side Panel.
> Additionally, you will see an entry for a new command Customize
> Layout. This new command triggers a new interactive quick pick
> experience allowing you to control all aspects of layout configuration
> in one place.

[image: customize layout demo]

----------- With v1.65:

> we are adding some options for everyone to try out with the setting
> `workbench.experimental.layoutControl.type`. This setting has the
> following options:
>
> Menu: This is the previous behavior with a single button that opens a
> menu.
>
> Toggles: This is a new option which shows three buttons to toggle the
> panel, side bar, and side panel.
>
> Both: This is a new option which shows the toggles followed by the
> menu button which still allows you to fairly quickly access the
> customize layout quick pick.

[image: v1.65 Layout Control]